# Не могу соединится, используя cURL (Unable to load client cert -8018)

Tags: curl, openssl

Когда я пытаюсь соединится, используя cURL:

```
curl 'https://example.com/' --cert ./newkey.pem -v -k
```

Я получаю ошибку:

```
* About to connect() to example.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 1.1.1.1... connected
* Connected to example.com (1.1.1.1) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* warning: ignoring value of ssl.verifyhost
* Unable to load client cert -8018.
* NSS error -8018
* Closing connection #0
curl: (58) Unable to load client cert -8018.
```

Предварительно я удалил pass phrase из приватного ключа RSA:

```
openssl rsa -in key.pem -out newkey.pem
```

Но это не решило проблему.

`$ curl --version`:

```
curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC
zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

Однако, данная команда работает корректно на другой машине, где `cURL` собран с  `OpenSSL`.
Как я понимаю, мне нужно добавить сертификат в NSS хранилище, но не пойму как это сделать. Пожалуйста подскажите решение данной проблемы